# How to make an active link in css

Tags: css

I am using the following code..actually i want to make an active link which highlights when it is acitive..could someone help me please !!!!

```
 .navbar-container{
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#B22222;
    position:fixed;
    }
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.navbar-container ul{
    list-style:none;
    }
.navbar-container ul li{
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    float:right;
    font-family:calibri;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
    }
.navbar-container ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    color:white;
    font-size:15pt;
    }
.navbar-container ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#620101;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.navbar-container ul li a:active {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: I mean when a link is active, red color is applied on all links!